# Adding header above navbar

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble style/adding a header above my navbar. I was able to add the header but the alignment is completely off.

I'm trying to have it align with the first navbar button. May I ask how do I create/edit my header such that it'll align with the navbar.

```
<div class="container" style="background-color: #00a3a3;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 class="pull-left" style="color: white">THE COMPANY NAME</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrwvNa

I was able to get it to align using this code

```
<nav class="navbar" style="background-color: #00a3a3;">
    <div class="container-fluid col-sm-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div>
            <h2 class="pull-left" style="color: white">THE COMPANY NAME</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

but there seems to be a space between the header and the nav bar.

Comment: here I'm not able to see any space between header and navbar. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o0c4Lo13/)

Comment: Hi Ahmad, please take a look at the code pen, you can see that example doesn't align with the nav bar Home button. And I stated that I was able to get it align using the navbar code for encapsulation, the JSFIddle you posted uses the Container class

Comment: Actually I'm not able to see any result on codepen, It's just showing Loading....... So I copied and pasted the same on jsfiddle. Still it's showing there Loading...........

Comment: Don't know what you are talking about. http://snag.gy/Cso74.jpg have a look at the link

Comment: here is the screenshot of my pc: [http://snag.gy/UigT1.jpg](http://snag.gy/UigT1.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution. Take a look in [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgoGRZ)

Change your `container` to `container-fluid` and use `margin-left:8.5%` in your `h1` header.

```
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #00a3a3;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2 class="pull-left" style="margin-left:8.5%;color: white">THE COMPANY NAME</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```